# Regex Issue- can't get it to accept my expression

Tags: objective-c, regex

I am running the following code, but my regex object is always nil and the error is telling me the regex is invalid (works fine in my regex tester!)

```
NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *pattern = @"({{[^}]*}})";
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern
                                                                           options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error: &err];
```

Do I need to escape anything in there? I tried adding \ before each curly brace, but that did not work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *two* backslashes as it is both the escape character for strings and for regular expressions, so `\\` enters a single backslash into the string, and then the regular expression parser sees the backslash and escapes the brace: `@"(\\{\\{[^}]*\\}\\})"`